# How to bring window from distant monitor in Windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Suppose I have several monitors connected and my desktop is expanded to them. Suppose that one monitor is far from me and I can't see it. Suppose I open some application, say Google Chrome, and it's window appears on that distant monitor.

Are there any means to bring such a window to another monitor in Windows (without disconnecting and reconfiguring)?

P.S. My taskbar is configured not to show window, which is on other monitor.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows + directional keys? It will move windows from monitors.

Answer (score 5):

The moment you start a program, it automatically has focus. As long as it has focus, you can use <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> to move the window to a different monitor.

Answer (score 1):

NirSoft's [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) can show you what windows are on what monitors and allows you to move them between them. You can even script it using the `/MoveWindow` command line option.